# How should I rename a reference in Entity Framework best?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know that it is an absolute beginner question but how should I rename references in EF?

Let you know, I have two simple tables they have a reference:

Product and Subproduct.

[image]

In my sql DataBase, the reference key is called "subproducts_ibfk_1" and the EF named it in "product1". How are you handle this?

Best regards

Comment: if you rename the field in your subproduct table from Product to ProductId then it should default the navigation property to product. It's only adding the 1 because you already have another field on that entity named product. You can also right click on product1 in the .edmx designer and change the name.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on your preference or your company's standard. The "standard" for SQL Server is sometimes FK_ForeignKeyTable_PrimaryKeyTable. So your example would be FK_subproduct_product.